# How to get the names of all power schemes in windows 7 in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, enumeration

I have to get the names of all available power schemes in windows 7. I try to enumerate them with the power management functions and I do get the right amount but when I call "PowerReadFriendlyName" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it works sometimes and fails sometimes:

```
UCHAR   displayBuffer[256];
DWORD   displayBufferSize = sizeof(displayBuffer);
GUID    buffer;
DWORD   bufferSize = sizeof(buffer);
int     index;
int     fail=0,ok=0;
//
for(index = 0 ; ; index++)
{   ZeroMemory(&buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    ZeroMemory(&displayBuffer, sizeof(displayBuffer));
    if (PowerEnumerate(NULL,NULL,NULL, ACCESS_SCHEME,index,(UCHAR*)&buffer,&bufferSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {   if (PowerReadFriendlyName(NULL, &buffer,&NO_SUBGROUP_GUID,NULL,displayBuffer,&displayBufferSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {   ok++;
            // stuff to todo
        }
        else
        {   fail++;
            // why?
        }
    }
    else
    {   break;
    }
}
```

At first I had 2 custom power schemes and the retrieval of their name always failed. The standard 3 power schemes (high performance, balanced, power saver) always worked.

So I thought it had to do with the custom schemes and I manually added 2 more of them. But as it turns out now one of them actually works and I can get its name (both were derived from balanced).

I then manually added another 2 custom schemes (this time derived from power saver) and this time both seemed to work. I now have 9 in total and I can get the names of 6 of them. I cannot get the name of the 2 original custom power schemes (both derived from balanced) as well as the 2nd of the ones I added the first time.

When I type "powercfg -list" in a console I can get the list of all power schemes, but how can I get the names of all power schemes reliably in c++ without redirecting/parsing the console but using the windows power management functions?

Comment: What is the return value of `PowerEnumerate()`/`PowerReadFriendlyName()` when they fail?  What is the value of `GetLastError()`?

Comment: Upon rechecking these values I noticed, that the description of the PowerReadFriendlyName() function seems to omit that the given length is overwritten even if the buffer is not NULL or the size too small which results in an error at the next pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of the PowerReadFriendlyName() function does not mention that the variable holding the length of the buffer gets overwritten in a successful call with a non-NULL buffer. It has therefore be set before each call of PowerReadFriendlyName() or it can fail:

```
UCHAR   displayBuffer[2048];
DWORD   displayBufferSize;
GUID    buffer;
DWORD   bufferSize = sizeof(buffer);
int     index;
int     fail=0,ok=0;
//
for(index = 0 ; ; index++)
{   ZeroMemory(&buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    ZeroMemory(&displayBuffer, sizeof(displayBuffer));
    if (PowerEnumerate(NULL,NULL,NULL, ACCESS_SCHEME,index,(UCHAR*)&buffer,&bufferSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {   displayBufferSize = sizeof(displayBuffer);
        if (PowerReadFriendlyName(NULL, &buffer,&NO_SUBGROUP_GUID,NULL,displayBuffer,&displayBufferSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {   ok++;
            // stuff to todo
        }
        else
        {   fail++;
        }
    }
    else
    {   break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are pretty clear: "BufferSize [in, out] ... If the specified buffer size is not large enough to hold the requested data, the function returns `ERROR_MORE_DATA` and **the variable receives the required buffer size**."

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: the docs say that the variable receives the required buffer size if the specified buffer size is not large enough, but are silent on what happens if the specified buffer size *is* large enough.  The OPs mistake was to assume that "if" really meant "if and only if".

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Ah if that's the case, then I agree that the documentation has an important omission of behavior here.

Comment: @HardCoder: for future reference, note that the behaviour you describe is typical of the Windows API, as is the ambiguity in the documentation.  If a variable is marked as Out or InOut, you should assume that it may be overwritten under any circumstances unless the documentation explicitly says that it won't be.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes, I learned that the hard way. I assumed the complete behaviour was documented and nothing left out but obviously that was not the case.